# How can I turn a Mac Mini into a dedicated wireless repeater?

Tags: linux, mac, wireless-networking, mac-mini, repeater

I have a Mac Mini (2007 model) that I'd like to turn into a dedicated Wireless Repeater. I have an additional USB Wi-Fi dongle for this.

I don't have Mac OS installed on it, nor do I want to. I was trying to achieve this by installing Ubuntu Server and setting the network cards and using hostapd and bridge-utils, but I was way over my head and couldn't figure it out.

I'd like to know if there is some complete guide explaining how to completely turn a computer into a dedicated wireless repeater, and/or if there is a distro specially suited for this that I can install on this Mac Mini.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems a bit overkill. Personally, I use an old Linksys WRT-54G with DD-WRT in repeater mode. Works great, uses little power, and should be just a few bucks used. Easy to set up too, since it does run a distro specially suited to it.

Comment: I'm with @ssmy. The energy costs of running a 2007 mini (which  had something like a 2 GHz Core 2 Duo processor) as a single-band 2x2 N AP (which is all it's capable of being) are going to outweigh the costs of picking up a low-end/used single-band 2x2 N AP, which would have used a low-power processor with just enough oomph to move frames at line rate.